# Ensure files on finder show the icon of the default app, not the old deleted app

Tags: finder, icon

I deleted an app that used to be the default app for a file type, but its icon still remains in Finder windows:

[image]

**How can I replace those icons for the icon of the current default app?**

Things I have already tried:

- Globally set the new app as default app for that type of file.
- Manually removed things related to the old app (as per [this tuto](http://www.uninstallmacapp.com/texstudio-removal.html)).
- Relaunched Finder and rebooted system.

My OS version is 10.11.6 (15G31) (El Capitan).

Any help kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to rebuild the Launch Services Database.
The simplest, non-techy way would be to use [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) (freeware)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I also re-set the new app as default and rebooted the system. Please let me know if you have another idea. Also, I'm OK with the _techy_ version too ;-)